# Как подсчитать количество уникальных пар?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, таблицы

Есть DataFrame, который состоит из двух столбцов: Имя, Номер заказа.

| Имя | Номер заказа |
| --- | --- |
| Вася | 123 |
| Петя | 254 |
| Вася | 123 |
| Петя | 678 |

Как в таком DataFrame можно грамотно посчитать кол-во таких заказов, для которых повторяется одно имя 2 и более раз?

Т.е., если смотреть на пример, то у Васи два заказа с одинаковым номером, мы их засчитаем как один. А у Пети два заказа с разными номерами, мы их не считаем совсем.

Если есть красивый способ с Pandas, было бы здорово. Либо же какая-то формула в Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы посчитать количество уникальных пар:

```
res = df.groupby(["name", "order"]).size().reset_index(name="count")
```

результат:

```
In [60]: res
Out[60]:
   name  order  count
0  Вася    123      2
1  Петя    254      1
2  Петя    678      1
```

дальше это можно отфильтровать так как вам необходимо:

```
In [62]: res.query("count > 1")
Out[62]:
   name  order  count
0  Вася    123      2
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то при исходных:

```
   name  order
0  Вася    123
1  Петя    254
2  Вася    123
3  Петя    678
```

можно попробовать так:

```
res = df.groupby("name", as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x[x.duplicated("order")].drop_duplicates()).set_index("name")
```

тогда res будет:

```
      order
name       
Вася    123
```